# Slice first character from paragraph element, replace content and add class. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

I am close to getting this function working, but not quite there yet.

The basic logic says find any p element that contains "+", strip the "+" from the text and try and replace the existing content with the new content and add a class.

Initially I had all of the matched elements being returned and concatenated into a single paragraph. So I tried to create an each function. I am now seeing the right results in the console, but I am not sure how to replace the content for the matched paragraph only (using $(this)).

I've made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/x4NRv/

Code below:

```
// remove bespoke text and add class 
$qmarkText = $('.post p:contains("+")').each(function() {
    $qStr = $(this).text().slice(1);
    $qmarkText.replaceWith('<p class="subhead-tumblr"' + $qStr + '</p>');
    console.log($qStr); 
});
```

I know that $qmarkText is not quite but not sure how to fix this, have tried several variations.

Hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: You do not need to assign to $qmarkText. Use $(this).text().replace

Answer (score 4):

You could use following snippet:

```
// remove bespoke text and add class 
$qmarkText = $('p').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().substring(0, 1) === "+"
}).each(function () {
    $qStr = $(this).text().slice(1);
    $(this).replaceWith('<p class="subhead-tumblr">' + $qStr + '</p>');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x4NRv/1/)

This avoid using `:contains()` which will match even character '+' is inside content text, not only at the beginning.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I knew p:contains() wasn't the most robust method.